# Можно ли с помощью первичного/внешнего ключа вывести все столбцы принадлежащие этому ключу?

Tags: sql

Вопрос в следующем, вид таблицы такой:

```
id first_namme last_name      email
1  Test_name   Last_test_Name Test@mail
```

id является первичным ключом, могу ли я с помощью SELECT или другой команды, выбрать все столбцы вызвав при этом только id = 1?

Я написал не правильно, у меня есть внешний ключ, т.е. другая таблица

```
id first_namme last_name      email     name_id 
1  Test_name   Last_test_Name Test@mail    1
```

Вот в этот name_id у меня присвоен внешний ключ в котором другие колонки, как мне эти колонки вывести с помощью внешнего ключа...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=1`? Или я не понял вопрос?

Comment: почитай про JOIN в SQL, там все просто

Comment: И когда делаю SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name_id=1 значения внешнего ключа не выводятся, я надеюсь понятно дообъяснял.

Comment: А без JOIN нельзя? Мне просто вывести значения нужно, объединять обязательно?

Comment: ну или просто запрос по двум таблицам `SELECT * FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.name_id=t2.id AND t1.id = 1`

Comment: но лучше join, он вроде как быстрее работает. Объединяет он только для запроса, на таблицах это не отразится

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Вообще-то `*` выводит все поля. Вы бы почитали что-нибудь по основам sql. Может быть узнаете смысл умных слов и может быть поставите вопрос правильно, чтобы все поняли. А может даже сами найдёте ответ.

Comment: Если не хватает знаний правильно выразить вопрос, воспользуйтесь примером. Т.е. задайте значения, какие есть в таблице, что на вход должно подаваться (вот у вас есть некий id=1), и что в результате должно получится (при этом включите в данные так же записи, которые _не должны_ попасть в результат, т.е. которые должны отфильтроваться). Так нам будет легче понять, что вы хотите.

Comment: Да все разобрался, там join нужен был...